# Does a human body age at any place at the same rate or can there be big differences?

Tags: human-biology

Aging can be caused by bad working mitochondrion, stacking of protein, shortening of telomers etc.

Now all our organs and materials have their own kind of cells, but are they equal vulnerable for aging by eating (which is the main cause of aging).

Probably there are some differences. For example the liver would get much more aged when drinking a lot of alcohol then one would get grey hair, because it is the task of the liver to break down toxic proteins etc. 
But can in general be said that the aging of the body goes equal throughout the whole body, or are there more/many special patterns for each organ which are dependent on the kind of food is taken?

So for example a person can have very 'young' intestines but a very old milt or can a person get grey hair but all other organs are very young?

Comment: how do you measurably define aging? also you should have googled this first, there seems to be a bit of info on interwebz http://io9.gizmodo.com/scientists-discover-parts-of-our-bodies-age-at-differen-1449085569

Comment: So besides the causes I mentioned in my question also DNA methylation (epigenitic cause) is a cause of aging. But in general can be said : 'For the most part, the chronological age of our body parts matches its biological age. But there are some exceptions, including female breast tissue.'?

Comment: i suggest editing your question so it has two parts: this is what you know, this is what you don't or dont understand